# Can the result of the function be saved in the loop as an object with a name containing the value i in R?

Tags: r

I want to write a script that will be used to choose the best degree of freedom for the spline function predictor in glm.

```
MODEL.1<-glm(ZAL ~ns(D1, df = i), data = DANE3, family =poisson, na.action=na.omit);
```

I wanted to use the loop to calculate sequentially models for values from 4 to 12, but I don't know how to make the loop save each model separately as an object, for example with the names "MODEL.df4", "MODEL.df5" and so on .

How can I code it in R?

Comment: Check out the [`assign`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/assign) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  You could store the results in a named list.  Here's a simple model function which returns a data.frame.

```
@library(tidyverse)
modelFn <- function(i){data.frame(IN = i, OUT = 7 + i)}
```

Initialize an empty list.

```
MODEL = NULL
```

Run the model against values from 4 to 12, and save the named result in your list

```
walk(4:12, ~ {MODEL[[paste0("df", .x)]] <<- modelFn(.x)})
```